# Can I use NightwatchJS or Selenium to verify the color used inside of multiple HTML5 canvas' on a page?

Tags: javascript, selenium, html5-canvas, jqplot, nightwatch.js

I'm helping out a healthcare provider who assists people in living healthier lives. Participants will join different programs like smoke prevention or healthy eating and their progress is tracked for several months. At the end of the program, reports are generated server side based on the number of participants and their progress. Each report has several number of bar, pie and/or donut charts displayed using an HTML5 canvas and jqplot.

Is there a way to automate the ability to go through each report and verify that each chart is using a specific color?

For example, if the smoking prevention section is using a bar chart, I would like Nightwatch or Selenium to be able to move down to that chart and verify the first bar in that chart is using the color Red. If that chart is using a pie chart broken into three slices, I would like the ability to verify the color for all three slices. Ultimately, I would need Nightwatch or Selenium to move through the report and perform this color test on all charts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: It's rather easy to get a [specific pixel's color in RGB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas), but I think it is rather hard to locate that pixel. In a pie chart, e.g., I have a hard time thinking of an easy way to identify all three slices. Would be easier, if SVG is used.

Comment: @Sirko Exactly! I was able to get the color of the first bar chart by manually hard coding the coordinates, but the issue is the test won't pass if someone runs it on a computer with a different window size. Having everything run automatically without hard coding the coordinates is the hard part, for me at least.